# Counting number of 1's or 0's in a row and displaying them?

Tags: php, mysql, database, rows

I am trying to create an admin notification system where on my database table named 'siteconfig' I have a row called setting='adminalerts' in this row will be certain alert columns such as:

nauseralert (non-activated user alert)
0 or 1
mmsitealert (maintenance mode site alert)
0 or 1

and so on...
I am trying to code something that will count the number of 0's or 1's in a row and display the value as a number. So if both of the above are set to 1, the value would be (2) and if there are only 1 alerts active it would be (1). If no alerts are active then it would show as (0) etc... Here is the code I have attempted to try but it doesn't seem to work? Was hoping for a little help here! Thanks!

```
<? 
 $sitealerts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM siteconfig WHERE setting='adminalerts'");
      $adminalerts = mysql_num_rows($sitealerts);
if ($nonactivated < 0){

     echo 'Admin Alerts';
    } else {
     echo 'No Alerts';
    }
     echo $adminalerts;
?>
```

I know this is probably totally wrong, but pretty new to this stuff and have tried to find about it online but not too sure I really understand how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to access the columns to calculate the right value:

```
$sitealerts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM siteconfig WHERE setting='adminalerts'");

//if the query was OK
if($sitealerts) {

    //loop through all result rows
    while(FALSE !== ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sitealerts))) {

        //do the calculation
        $count = 0;
        $count += intval($row['nauseralert']);
        $count += intval($row['mmsitealert']);
        if($count > 0) {
            print $count;
        }
        print '<br />';
    }
    mysql_free_result($sitealerts);
}
```

Comment: Absolutely spot on! Works a treat, thanks very much!

Comment: Is there a way to make it show a black space instead of 0 if there are no errors?

Answer (score 0):

mysql is dprecated in php 5.5 http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php
it is better to use mysqli.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
// checking connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    exit();
}
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT (nauseralert+mmsitealert) as alerts_count FROM siteconfig WHERE setting='adminalerts'")) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        if($row['alerts_count']) 
           echo $row['alerts_count'];
        else echo ' ';
    }
    $result->close();
}
$mysqli->close();
```